# Стили не применяются к <body> с добавленным классом через classList в React?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, reactjs, postcss

В методе componentWillMount внутри компонента делаю следующее

```
   window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);
```

Функция

```
 export const handleFirstTab = e => {
if (e.keyCode === 9) {

    document.body.classList.add('user-is-tabbing');

    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);

}
```

};

В стилях у меня

```
 body:not(.user-is-tabbing) button:focus,
body:not(.user-is-tabbing) textarea:focus {
outline: none;
 }

body.user-is-tabbing *:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #7AACFE !important; 
}
```

Но стили не применяются к новому body c классом user-is-tabbing. Нужно как-то пеерендовать компонент? Инлайново не хочется добавлять стили. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы как проверяете что не применяется? Первое что в голову приходит, может вы смотрите на элементах на которых в голом виде :focus не работает (ну там голые дивки без табиндекса)? В общем мне кажется вам надо еще дальше декомпозировать проблему

Comment: хочу в проект на реате внедрить вот такое поведение https://codepen.io/davidgilbertson/pen/LjGzGw

Comment: по сути я добавляю же в body все, которого нет в реакте как бы

Comment: вроде да, поэтому возможно проблема и не в этом. Но зачем делать это через прямое взаимодействие с body все равно неясно, потому что инкапсуляцию Вы все же нарушаете. Что мешает стили на реактовский кусок дерева навешать а не на body? Если пристального взгляда недостаточно, можно слегка уточнить место ошибки, из этого кода есть еще убирать чтобы легче было понять *где именно* все сломалось.

Comment: Начнем с того, вы в проекте своем проверяете или в сниппете? если в проекте попробуйте сделать сниппет где нибудь на jsfiddle, вдруг зверь зарыт не здесь. Потом попробуйте упростить цсс селекторы до умопомрачения, потом обработчик

Comment: соверешнно дожный работать код! надо открыть инспектор и смотреть что происходит